# Fourier transform of Bessel function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fourier-transform, integration, quantum-optics

Please help me find the the representation in $k$-space (Fourier transform) of the following function:
$$
f(k_t, k_z, m) = J_m(k_t\rho)\exp(ik_zz)\exp(im\phi)/N
$$

The properties of $f$ given below might come in handy. The equations are from a paper by S.J. Van Enk and G. Nienhuis(2007) (https://doi.org/10.1080/09500349414550911) eqns.35 and 36 under the 4th subheading.
$$
(\hat{P}^2_x + \hat{P}^2_y)f = \hbar^2k_t^2f,\\ \hat{P}_zf = \hbar k_zf\\ \hat{L}_zf = \hbar m f
$$

Answer (score 0):

The $k_z$ is irrelevent, so this is just a two-dimensional problem.

I suspect that this is a homework problem, so I'll just give a hint:

Start by showing that if  you have a function of the form $f(r,\theta)=f(r)e^{-il\theta}$ then the integral definition of the Bessel function $J_l(kr)$ shows that the  two dimensional Fourier transform is
$$
\tilde f({\bf k})= 2\pi i^l e^{-il\theta_k} \int_0^\infty J_l(kr)f(r)r dr.
$$
Here $k$, $\theta_k$ are the polar coordinates of the vector ${\bf k}=(k_x,k_y)$.
Now you can use the Hankel transform formula
$$
\int_0^\infty J_l(kr) J_l(k'r) rdr = \frac 1 k \delta(k-k'),
$$
(which is just a disguised version of the Fourier inversion theorem) to evaluate your FT.

Comment: I am not getting J(kr) when I evaluate the theta integral.

Comment: Perhaps you could show your work?  The answer to the FT should be $\propto k^{-1}\delta(k-k_t) e^{im \theta_k}$

Comment: When I evaluate the integral over theta I am getting $J_{l}(k_{x}r)+(-i^{l})J_{l}(k_{y}r )$. By integral definition of Bessel function you mean the formula $J_{n}(x)=\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{i(xsint-nt)}dt$, right? Could you show your working, It is not a homework question?

Comment: Never mind, I got it, thanks for your help.

Comment: @Joel Sunil Could you write your solution as an answer? It will help people who are attracted by the title of your question.